# Fixing django csrf error when using uploadify

Tags: django, uploadify, django-csrf

I'm using uploadify in my django admin but I'm getting a 403 error. When I use **@csrf_exempt** the error is gone but this is very risky.

Is there a better way to fix this problem without compromising the admin page by using @csrf_exempt decorator?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Allthough Paul has pointed the reason for this issue, he did not propose a solution to this. For anyone using Django and jQuery it would be interesting to get a bit more specific on this topic, as not everyone has the time to learn actionscript.

Comment: @ginad I have a similar problem, but different. I have been trying to send the token and make the verification using @sultan 's hacky solution, but it didn't work for me. This question is three years old and based on a Django's older version for sure. However I took a look to the `CsrfViewMiddleware` source and what I saw leads me to think that sending the token through `formData` and try to verificate it from Django is not secure enough. Maybe I am too confused right now, but probably the only way to do this with full security is adapting `uploadify.swf` itself...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like either you or the original author of that package need to update it to work with the changes that have come through in the CSRF framework. Sorry that's not the easy answer... :/

You'll need to make sure the ajax requests are sending cookies properly, and more importantly, that you're sending the CSRF token as part of the posted data. Prior to the CSRF security patch, ajax requests weren't required to be CSRF protected because we believed they couldn't be forged cross domain. Unfortunately, this isn't true, and so we had to require the CSRF tokens for those as well.

In particular, see this relevant portion of the docs:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Edit:

It looks like the flash portion of uploadify doesn't send the cookies for whatever reason. It probably worked before because it was sending an AJAX header. Now it needs to send that cookie regardless, so the correct solution here is to modify the flash to send the cookie.

Comment: thanks paul, but uploadify is not sending the data in ajax. The data are sent using a multipart post.

Answer (score 1):

@Paul McMillan I faced the same problem with `csrf` protection of a view and made a small & ugly workaround to provide basic csrf validation, here is the code

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware

def check_uploadify_csrf(request):
    return CsrfViewMiddleware().process_view(request, check_uploadify_csrf, None, None) == None

@csrf_exempt
def some_view(request):
    if check_uploadify_csrf(request):
        # do some actions
```

@ginad I used uploadify option `formData` to send csrf token to backend

`formData: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},`

Thanks,

Sultan

Comment: I tried this same solution, but `check_uploadify_csrf()` function imported into `views.py` instead of defining it inside. If the function returns something, my code triggers `HttpResponseForbidden()` on purpose. However, I can clearly see that `formData` is sending the token to Django server successfully via POST, so I don't get why `check_uploadify_csrf()` keeps returning something...

Comment: Hmmm... it seems that the middleware will look into `request.META['CSRF_COOKIE']`... Does this mean that it is not enough with sending the cookie's token to prevent a CSRF attack, but the entire cookie itself has to be send through metadata in HTTP requests? Does this mean that the only way to resolve this issue would be modifying `uploadify.swf` itself to send the cookie, and there's no other way to grant CSRF protection, as @PaulMcMillan said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5658919/3692177)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to http://blog.fogtunes.com/2009/11/howto-integrate-swfupload-with-django/ I was able to solve my problem.

Javascript:

```
function getCookie(cname)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if(x == cname){
        return unescape(y);
      }
    }
return false;}
```

> data = { 
>           sessionid: getCookie('sessionid'),
>       csrfmiddlewaretoken:  csrf_token
>       }
>       $('#file_upload').uploadify({
>             // pass the cookie and the csrftoken
>             scriptData : data,
>             .... // other codes
>        });

Middleware:

```
#insert after: 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware'
def process_request(self, request):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        if request.POST.has_key('csrfmiddlewaretoken'):
            request.COOKIES["csrftoken"] = request.POST['csrfmiddlewaretoken']
        if request.POST.has_key('sessionid'):
            request.COOKIES['sessionid'] = request.POST['sessionid']
```

because uploadify is not passing the cookie I need to pass it using POST, then before processing the view the middleware will set the cookie.

Comment: You've essentially disabled the CSRF protection here. This is exactly the same thing as setting your form to be CSRF exempt. The protection relies on the fact that a malicious site can't set cookies in your browser on your domain. You've neatly bypassed that. It sounds like the flash component of uploadify doesn't send the proper cookie. That would be where it should be fixed.

Comment: What if there would be a direct check for the correct value of csrfmiddlewaretoken and session_id? The main issue is that Djangos CSRF protection relies on a CSRF cookie, and uploadify doesn't pass the cookie. But it can pass the values of the csrfmiddlewaretoken and the session_id via scriptData. Wouldn't it preserve the CSRF protection telling Django not to look for the csrf-cookie, but for the relevant values inside request.POST?

Comment: What i essentially wanted to say: Do not set "biscuit" blindly, but after a check for the important values (csrfmiddlewaretoken, sessionid, what else?). I think that could work, allthough i am not sure i have fully understood the mechanism of csrf protection...